# How does the coffee machine work?

Tags: breaking-bad

Can somebody explain how this absolute amazing coffee machine works in the lab of Walter White in *Breaking Bad*?

[image]

Comment: I think the only part of it that could be explained by us is Gayle's own description of the process he used, which was pretty brief.  It involved ensuring the brewing coffee never went over a critical temperature that started to produce undesirable chemicals (which made the coffee more bitter?).  ..Is that black oblong object on the left of the bench a ..camera?  I suspect Gus would not have been cool with a camera being in his super-lab!

Comment: *"..Is that black oblong object on the left of the bench a ..camera?"*  Nope.  When I expand the image, it becomes clear it is the front panel of the heating unit beneath the Erlenmeyer flask(?).  The 'lens' is simply a shiny black knob to set the temperature.

Comment: Related questions on [Coffee.SE](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1535/203) and [Chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7439/16299).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson thanks for the links! Haven't found them on the stackoverflow sites.

Comment: This isn't really a movies/TV question. Maybe ask on engineering.se? Coffee.se? ScienceFiction.se?

Comment: Let's also discuss the hazards of food prep in a meth lab.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this really isn't a question about a movie or TV show and would be better addressed elsewhere, as mentioned in the comments.